# How to create a dynamic JSONObject?

Tags: java, semantic-web, json

I have a little problem
I've write a code that create an object from JSONObject and add some data on it like this:

```
JSONObject outerObject = new JSONObject();
JSONArray outerArray = new JSONArray();

JSONObject innerObject1 = new JSONObject();

innerObject1.put("id", "semantic web");
innerObject1.put("url", "www.semanticweb.com");
innerObject1.put("definition", "this is the denfition of semantic web");
outerArray.put(innerObject1);
```

then I create another one called innerObject2 and do the same process like this:

```
JSONObject innerObject2 = new JSONObject();

innerObject2.put("id", "ontology");
innerObject2.put("url", "www.ontology.com");
innerObject2.put("definition", "this is the denfition of ontology");
outerArray.put(innerObject2);

outerObject.put("rows", outerArray);
return outerObject.toString();
```

the results will be some thing like this:

```
{"rows":[{"definition":"this is the denfition of semantic web","id":"semantic web","url":"www.semanticweb.com"},{"definition":"this is the denfition of ontology","id":"ontology","url":"www.ontology.com"}]}
```

My problem is: what if I want to create another JSONObject called innerObject3 , innerObject4 , innerObject5 .... etc using for loop?
any suggestions?

Comment: You could use `gson` or similar helper library to manipulate java object to json object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your response
I've manage to solve this problem as follow:

```
JSONObject outerObject = new JSONObject();
JSONArray outerArray = new JSONArray();

JSONObject [] innerObject = new JSONObject[4];
for(int i =0; i<3; i++)
{
    innerObject[i]=new JSONObject();
    innerObject[i].put("id", "id of "+i);
    innerObject[i].put("url", "url of "+i);
    innerObject[i].put("Definition", "Definition of "+i);
    outerArray.put(innerObject[i]);
}
outerObject.put("rows", outerArray);
return outerObject.toString();
```

hope that this can help others :)